# Best way to implement ban after too many login attempts

Tags: php, security, authentication, ip

I've been researching this for the last 2 days after I implemented my own system for banning too many attempts. But I haven't found the proper answer I am looking for. Which pretty much is, what is the best way to implement this?

Currently I have this implemented through an IP ban, if the same IP consecutively makes a login mistake 10 times, the IP is banned for 30 minutes from being able to sign in, they can browse the website still.  However if this occured at a high population area, such as a university campus, wouldn't this effectively block the whole school from signing in?

So is there a better way to do this, that doesn't use IP addresses? I was thinking I could do it with cookies, but the user trying to brute force an account could simply delete their cookies after every 10 attempts.

Comment: You should re-use an existing authentication framework whenever possible, because, really, it's complex. For example, take a look at https://github.com/delight-im/PHP-Auth which is both framework-agnostic and database-agnostic. It does throttling, which is what you want, automatically.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An approach I've followed once is similar to the one I encountered on my bank's e-banking page. It prohibits further logins for an increasing amount of time on a per account basis, say 5 tries, where you wait 10s, 1min, 5 min, 15 min, then 30 min for example.
An attacker usually targets a specific account. There should also be a global rule applied per IP address, which locks login after a certain number of tries, which must be more than 5, say 10. Additionally to both rules, you can compare browsers and cookies etc. for increased tolerance.

Comment: the problem with this still though, is it blocks all the users on that ip and gives them increasing wait times, which is the same issue i already have with the implementation i am using.

Comment: I mean increasing wait times for the targeted account, but not for others. You may also evaluate cookies as long as you can. Should there be no cookie to track, other measures may be taken. A pure bruteforce attack without proper client info can just be blocked by IP or partially by IP:port of a persistent connection.

Comment: oh i see what you mean, yes that would be quite effective, i should have thought of that before ;)

Answer (score 8):

Create mysql table called "failed_logins" with two fields, a "User" field/foreign key and a "Timestamp" field.

When a user successfully logs in, delete all "failed_logins" rows for that user.

When a user unsuccessfully logs in, create a new row in "failed_logins" for that user with the current timestamp.

On every login attempt for a given user, BEFORE checking to see if password is correct/incorrect:

- run a query deleting all "failed_logins" rows older than 15 minutes (for example).
- run a query checking the count of rows in failed_logins for the user attempting to login. If >= 5 (for example), kill the login attempt, notifying the user they have been locked out of their account and to try back in a little while.

Result:
Users are locked out of their account after 5 failed login attempts within 15 minutes.