# How can rate limiter be used per userId?

Tags: node.js, express, express-rate-limit

We are currently using rate limiter which from my understanding limits requests per user IP. Example code below

```
import rateLimit from 'express-rate-limit'

const apiLimiter = rateLimit({
    windowMs:  10000, // 10 seconds
    max: 1, 
    standardHeaders: true, 
    legacyHeaders: false, 
})

app.use('/api', apiLimiter, //endpoint)
```

Is it possible to use rate limiter per userId incase requests are sent from multiple devices at once which will have different IPs

Comment: So how do you know all of these multiple requests from different IP are same userId ?

Comment: What I mean is using rate limiter based on user Id or email, specific identifier that will be available in req.user instead of ip @VivekRahul

Comment: you can create a middleware that will track the userid from request and increase the route visit that you can store in some database like redis. You can limit the user request if that count exceeds.

Comment: @dark In that case you cant use rate limiter. Check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9153554/best-way-to-implement-ban-after-too-many-login-attempts

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can set a custom `keyGenerator` to return a userId rather than an IP address:

```js
import rateLimit from 'express-rate-limit'

const apiLimiter = rateLimit({
    windowMs:  10000, // 10 seconds
    max: 1, 
    standardHeaders: true, 
    legacyHeaders: false,
    keyGenerator: function(req) {
      // return the user id for the request here
    } 
})

app.use('/api', apiLimiter, //endpoint)
```

The `keyGenerator` function may also be `async` or return a `Promise` if you can't determine userId synchronously.

---

Disclosure: I'm the author of express-rate-limit.